# Why is my Javascript memory match game doing weird stuff?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a memory match game with 2 difficulties: one with 12 tiles and the other with 24 tiles. The small one works fine, but the large one does some weird stuff. When you click on a tile from the bottom 2 rows, the images on the top two rows appear for some reason, but when you click on the top 2 rows, nothing happens. No error shows up in the console either.

I'm new to JavaScript and I really want this to work.

Here is my code:

```
 /* Global Variables */
 var picks;    //counts how may picks have been made in each turn
 picks = 0;
 var elect;    //counts how may picks have been made in each turn
 elect = 0;

var firstchoice;    //stores index of first card selected
var secondchoice;   //stores index of second card selected
var choosefirst    //stores index of first card selected hard
var choosesecond   //stores index of second card selected hard
var cntr = 0;     //counts matches made
var numAttempts = 0; //counts attempts made
var numOfMatches = 6; //counts number of matches made
var numOfPairs = 12; //counts the number of matches made ofr the hard mode
var backcard ="cardfront.jpg";    //shows back of card when turned over
var faces = [];   //array to store card images
var output = document.querySelector("#output");
var score = 0; //calculates the score
var strikeCntr = 1; // counts the number of strikes against the player
faces[0] = 'enterprise.jpg';
faces[1] = 'borgcube.jpg';
faces[2] = 'klingonbp.jpg';
faces[3] = 'romulanwb.jpg';
faces[4] = 'dsnine.jpg';
faces[5] = 'ferengiship.png';
faces[6] = 'enterprise.jpg';
faces[7] = 'borgcube.jpg';
faces[8] = 'klingonbp.jpg';
faces[9] = 'romulanwb.jpg';
faces[10] = 'dsnine.jpg';
faces[11] = 'ferengiship.png';

var cards = [];
cards[0] = 'enterprise.jpg';
cards[1] = 'borgcube.jpg';
cards[2] = 'klingonbp.jpg';
cards[3] = 'romulanwb.jpg';
cards[4] = 'dsnine.jpg';
cards[5] = 'ferengiship.png';
cards[6] = 'cardassian.jpg';
cards[7] = 'defiant.jpg';
cards[8] = 'dominion.jpg';
cards[9] = 'shuttlecraft.jpg';
cards[10] = 'vulcan.jpg';
cards[11] = 'enterprisenx01.jpg';
cards[12] = 'enterprise.jpg';
cards[13] = 'borgcube.jpg';
cards[14] = 'klingonbp.jpg';
cards[15] = 'romulanwb.jpg';
cards[16] = 'dsnine.jpg';
cards[17] = 'ferengiship.png';
cards[18] = 'cardassian.jpg';
cards[19] = 'defiant.jpg';
cards[20] = 'dominion.jpg';
cards[21] = 'shuttlecraft.jpg';
cards[22] = 'vulcan.jpg';
cards[23] = 'enterprisenx01.jpg';


// select the easy mode or hard mode
var easy = document.getElementById('easyGame');

easyGame = function() {
var div = document.getElementById('easy');
if (div.style.display === 'none') 
{
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
};

var hard = document.getElementById('hardGame');

hardGame = function() {
var div = document.getElementById('hard');
if (div.style.display === 'none') 
{
    div.style.display = 'block';
}

};
//shuffle the cards
function shuffleArray(array) {
for (var i = faces.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = faces[i];
    faces[i] = faces[j];
    faces[j] = temp;
}
return array;
}

//shuffle the cards
function arrayShuffle(array) {
for (var i = cards.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[j];
    cards[j] = temp;
}
return array;
}



//* Responds to click on a table cell indicating card selected */
function choose(card) {

if (picks==2) {   //if 2 picks made, do nothing
return ;
}
if (picks==0) {   //if first pick, identify card selected
firstchoice=card;
document.images[card].src = faces[card];
picks = 1;    //one pick made
}
else
{ picks = 2;   //second pick, identify card selected
secondchoice = card;
document.images[card].src =faces[card];
tid=setInterval("check()",1000); //use timer to pause so user can see selections
}
}

//* Responds to click on a table cell indicating card selected */
function choice(face) {
if (elect==2) {   //if 2 picks made, do nothing
return ;
}
if (elect==0) {   //if first pick, identify card selected
choosefirst=face;
document.images[face].src = cards[face];
elect = 1;    //one pick made
}
else
{ elect = 2;   //second pick, identify card selected
choosesecond = face;
document.images[face].src =cards[face];
tid=setInterval("look()",1000); //use timer to pause so user can see selections
}
}


//* Check to see if a match is made */
function check() {
clearInterval(tid); //stop timer
numAttempts++;   //add 1 to attempts
document.getElementById("attempts").innerHTML = numAttempts; //display number of attempts
if (faces[secondchoice]===faces[firstchoice]) 
{   //if a match is selected
score++;
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
 cntr++;    //add 1 to matches
 if (cntr === numOfMatches) {  //if matches made = maximum possible matches, display message
      alert("You won.\n It took you " + numAttempts + " attempts.\n Click New Game to play     again.");
      return false;
     }    
 picks = 0;
  return;
}
else {  //if no match made, turn cards back over
document.images[firstchoice].src = backcard;
document.images[secondchoice].src = backcard;
document.getElementById("strikes").innerHTML = strikeCntr;
strikeCntr++;
if(strikeCntr===5)
    {
               alert("Game Over");
               return false;

    }
picks = 0;
return ;
   }
}

/* Check to see if a match is made */
function look() {
 clearInterval(tid); //stop timer
 numAttempts++;   //add 1 to attempts
 document.getElementById("attempts").innerHTML = numAttempts; //display number of attempts
 if (cards[choosesecond]===cards[choosefirst]) 
{   //if a match is selected
score++;
document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
 cntr++;    //add 1 to matches
 if (cntr === numOfPairs) {  //if matches made = maximum possible matches, display message
      alert("You won.\n It took you " + numAttempts + " attempts.\n Click New Game to play again.");
      return false;
     }    
 elect = 0;
  return;
 }
else {  //if no match made, turn cards back over
document.images[choosefirst].src = backcard;
document.images[choosesecond].src = backcard;
document.getElementById("strikes").innerHTML = strikeCntr;
strikeCntr++;
if(strikeCntr===5)
    {
               alert("Game Over");
               return false;

    }
elect = 0;
return ;
   }
}


// make a game timer
var timeLeft = 60;
var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown() {
if (timeLeft == 0) {
clearTimeout(timerId);
alert("Game Over");
  } 
else {
output.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds remaining';
timeLeft--;
}
}


function newGame() // loading new page
{
location.reload(true);
}
```

Also I can't get the number of attempts, strikes, or the score to appear in the hard mode of the game.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vulcan Mind Training</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <p id="output">Text</p>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="MemoryMatchTestNew.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Table to hold game board -->
    <table id="easy" style="display:none">
        <tr>
            <!-- javascript:choose() calls the choose() function when cell is
            clicked and passes the value in brackets to the function identifying
            which cell was clicked -->
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(0)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(1)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(2)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(3)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(4)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(5)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(6)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(7)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(8)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(9)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(10)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:choose(11)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a> </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr><td><a href="javascript:shuffleArray()">Shuffle cards</a></td></tr> 
                    <tr>
            <td>No. of Attempts</td>
            <td id="attempts">0</td>
            <td>Score</td>
            <td id="score">0</td>
            <td>Strikes</td>
            <td id="strikes"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="hard" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(0)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(1)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(2)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(3)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(4)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(5)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(6)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(7)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(8)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(9)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(10)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(11)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(12)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(13)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(14)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(15)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(16)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(17)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(18)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(19)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(20)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(21)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(22)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:choice(23)"><img src="cardfront.jpg" width=150 height=150></a></td>
    </tr>
     <tr><td><a href="javascript:arrayShuffle()">Shuffle cards</a></td></tr> 
                    <tr>
            <td>No. of Attempts</td>
            <td id="attempts">0</td>
            <td>Score</td>
            <td id="score">0</td>
            <td>Strikes</td>
            <td id="strikes"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input id="newGame" type="button" value="New Game" onclick="newGame();"/> 
    <input id="easyGame" type="button" value="Student" onclick="easyGame();"/>
    <input id="hardGame" type="button" value="Kolinar Master" onclick="hardGame();"/>     
</body>
</html>
```

What is causing this to happen?
I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would help if you could narrow down the problem a little bit and only show us the relevant parts of your code or create a demo with very specific reproduction steps and your thoughts about the problem.

Comment: One potential problem I think I can see is that you have two global arrays faces and cards and cards is used in some of your functions and faces in others. Possibly a scoping problem?

Comment: I find it unnecessary to implement generic code as static code; however creating this table using javascript is much easier to control and more importantly much easier to read and debug.